# https uri request returning bad request when using proxy

Tags: wpf, https, proxy

We are experiencing problem to deploy our WPF application in one of our customers. The application works great while calling our web APIs (hosted at azure) using HTTP protocol.
But when it must download a blob located at Azure (using HTTPS uri) we get a 400 bad request return.

It seems this customer has some special network policy and surely there is a forward proxy involved.

When there is not "network management" and we can have direct internet access, everything goes fine.

How can I fix that? Is there anything I can make on the application side? What would be the changes on the proxy (if any)?

Thank you,

Igor.